# 400 Bad Request in Apollo Client querying Django Backend

Tags: reactjs, django, graphql, apollo-client, graphene-django

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to make a GraphQL query using Apollo Client in my React frontend from my Django/Django Rest/Graphene Backend. I have also gotten some CORS errors so I have disabled cors on the client with:

```
fetchOptions: {
        mode: "no-cors",
      },
```

and on the backend with `csrf_exempt`.

I am able to make the query work just fine in Postman and GraphiQL but not in React.

Here is my query:

```
export const STOCKS_BY_ADJ_CLOSE_RANGE_AND_DATE_QUERY = gql`
  query StocksByAdjCloseRangeAndDate {
    stocksByAdjCloseRangeAndDate(
      low: 100
      high: 105
      start: "2024-03-01T00:00:00Z"
      end: "2024-03-10T00:00:00Z"
    ) {
      ticker
      datetime
      open
      high
      low
      close
      adjClose
      volume
    }
  }
`;
```

Here is my client:

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    console.log("graphQLErrors", graphQLErrors);
  }
  if (networkError) {
    console.log("networkError", networkError);
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },
  connectToDevTools: true,
  link: from([
    errorLink,
    new HttpLink({
      uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql",
      fetchOptions: {
        mode: "no-cors",
      },
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
      },
    }),
  ]),
});
```

Here are my Django routes:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path("", router.urls),
    # path("", include(router.urls)),
    path(
        "api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls", namespace="rest_framework")
    ),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    # path("", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="frontend/build/index.html")),
    path("api/", include(router.urls)),
    path("", home),
    path(
        r"graphql",
        csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True, schema=schema)),
    ),
]
```

Here are my backend schema definitions

```
class StockNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        filter_fields = ["ticker"]
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)


class StockModelType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    stocks = DjangoFilterConnectionField(StockNode)
    first_stock = graphene.List(StockNode, ticker=graphene.String())
    stocks_by_ticker = graphene.List(StockNode, ticker=graphene.String())
    stocks_by_datetime = graphene.List(
        StockNode, start=graphene.DateTime(), end=graphene.DateTime()
    )
    stocks_by_adj_close_range = graphene.List(
        StockNode, low=graphene.Float(), high=graphene.Float()
    )
    stocks_by_adj_close_range_and_date = graphene.List(
        StockNode,
        low=graphene.Float(),
        high=graphene.Float(),
        start=graphene.DateTime(),
        end=graphene.DateTime(),
    )

    def resolve_first_stock(self, info):
        return Stock.objects.first()

    def resolve_stocks(self, info):
        return Stock.objects.all()

    def resolve_stocks_by_ticker(self, info, ticker: str):
        return Stock.objects.filter(ticker=ticker)

    def resolve_stocks_by_datetime(self, info, start: str, end: str):
        return Stock.objects.filter(
            datetime__gte=start, datetime__lte=end
        ).distinct()

    def resolve_stocks_by_adj_close_range(self, info, low: float, high: float):
        return Stock.objects.filter(
            adj_close__gte=low, adj_close__lte=high
        ).distinct()

    def resolve_stocks_by_adj_close_range_and_date(
        self, info, low: float, high: float, start: str, end: str
    ):
        return (
            Stock.objects.filter(adj_close__gte=low, adj_close__lte=high)
            .distinct()
            .filter(datetime__gte=start, datetime__lte=end)
        ).distinct()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction here? I'm at a loss as to why this would work everywhere except in React. :(

Comment: It seems that removing ```fetchOptions: {
        mode: "no-cors",
      },``` fixes it. I'm not sure why that would be, but whatever.

Comment: You have to configure CORS on the server. All the options you put in your HttpLink here are headers that the server should sent to the client, not the client to the server.

Comment: @phry Thanks that makes sense. It is odd because I had configured some CORS stuff on the server but not those headers specifically so I guess that was the issue.